# Strip special characters from string, retain, alphabets, numbers and punctuation marks

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to clean a string from all special characters and retain everything else, including punctuation marks.

```
mystring = "Q18. On a scale from 0 to 10 where 0 means â€˜not at all interested' and 10 means â€˜very interested', how interested are you in helping to address problems that affect poor people in poor countries?"
```

My effort so far:

```
newlabel = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', newstring)
```

Output:

```
Q18 On a scale from 0 to 10 where 0 means not at all interested and 10 means very interested how interested are you in helping to address problems that affect poor people in poor countries
```

How can I retain the punctuation marks in the regex I currently have or is there a better solution?

Comment: Do you really have that unicode character before `very interested'`?

Comment: Yep. No idea why or how, but its there and I want to get rid of it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved,

```
print (newstring.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii','ignore'))
```

Output:

```
Q18. On a scale from 0 to 10 where 0 means not at all interested' and 10 means very interested', how interested are you in helping to address problems that affect poor people in poor countries?
```

Comment: Did you refer something else to come up with that solution?

Comment: Once you said they were "unicodes" I did a quick search and found the answer here: http://bit.ly/1nSSmjY

Comment: Great. I am marking this question as a dup of that question. It will be helpful for the future readers.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to change is to retain the dot than adding it to the regex will solve that.

```
re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9\.]+', ' ', mystring)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add backslash before each punctuation mark in the regular expression .....